# How can i map '%' key by vim？

Tags: vim, vi

When use vim , use '%' can jump {,[,( to },],)。

But need to press shift+5，I want to map Tab+5 to %　like：

```
map <Tab>5 %
map <Tab>5 <S-5>
map <Tab>5 <S-%>
map <Tab>5 <ESC>%
map <Tab>5 <ESC><S-5>
```

all map are fail，can someone know how to map？

Comment: you want to map `<tab>+5` or `<tab> then 5` ?

Comment: your mapping (the first one) works here, please notice that, in your question, ` {（［` are not `{ ( [` make sure that they are normal ascii chars.

Comment: you probably want `nnoremap` here.